# Paypal integration with php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, integration

How to get started with Paypal integration with php codeigniter? Where should i start? Any suggestion?

Comment: Here is the paypal libraray for codeigniter very helpful library.
https://www.angelleye.com/product/codeigniter-paypal-sdk-class-library/

Answer (score 7):

Here's a good starting point:

[PayPal library for CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/)

I haven't personally worked with the library, but you should find plenty of support in [the CodeIgniter forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/). Just do a search for PayPal.

Good luck.

Comment: Dead link: PayPal library for CodeIgniter?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an updated link for the library, but here's some friendly advice: it's time to move away from CodeIgniter.